# Work done by vibrating string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, work, string

[image]

figure from http://webusers.physics.illinois.edu/~m-stone5/mma/notes/amaster.pdf

The string has fixed ends, a mass per unit length of $\rho$, and is under tension $T$. This [source](http://webusers.physics.illinois.edu/~m-stone5/mma/notes/amaster.pdf) claims that "the rate that a segment of string is doing work on its neighbour to the right" is

$$
-T\dfrac{\mbox{d} y}{\mbox{d} x}\dfrac{\mbox{d}y}{\mbox{d}        t}
$$

without any justification. I have no idea how this is derived. I would like to see a simple (if possible) derivation. I wonder in what way can the a segment of the string $dx$ can do work to the neighboring segment on the right since in the context of this problem there is no movement in the x-axis (right?).

Comment: Approximation: the string's motion is wholly up and down. So consider any point on the string: the angle it makes with the horizontal is $\theta \approx \tan\theta = \partial_x y$. The vertical component of the tension force on the section to the left of point in question by section to the right is $T \sin\theta \approx T\tan\theta = T \partial_x y$. The point's velocity is $\partial_t y$ vertically. Therefore $\vec{F} \cdot \vec{v}$ = rate of working by right hand section on  left hand section is $T \,\partial_t y \,\sin\theta \approx T\,\partial_t y\, \partial_x y$. Now switch the sign.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance, does it make sense to talk about the angle a point makes with the horizontal? Or were you talking about a short segment on the string? Got your point though.

Comment: No, but it does make sense to talk about the angle the tangent at that point makes with the horizontal, and this is what you need to know: it is the direction that the tension acts in. We have an idealised string that is althogether flimsy - so it can't support any force normal to its tangent. It can only impart force by becoming tight and tethering something.

Answer (score 3):

The equation represents power = force times velocity. The force used is the restoring force of a small string segment ${\rm d}x$ which is equal to $-T \tan \theta = -T \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$.

The velocity of the segment is obviously $\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}t}$.

You can do the math yourself to balance the forces for a small segment, and will arrive at the same thing.